# How to delete all my application achievements?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, curl, facebook-opengraph, achievements

Is there a fast way to delete all the achievements I've created for my Facebook app? (I got hundreds..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need to delete each one individually